# canvas.create_window not working?

Tags: user-interface, canvas, tkinter, widget

I want to place a widget in my canvas.
I have written the following function to create a button and display it.
 in the center of the x coordinate of my canvas.

```
def Button_Placer():
label1=Label(canvas, width =20, height = 2, font = font2, text="")
label1.pack()
def Show_Name():
    name=NameGenerator()
    label1.config(text=name)
button1=Button(canvas, text="Generate Name", width=20, height=4, font=font1, command=Show_Name)
button1=canvas.create_window(250, 300)
```

I have also created a canvas at the top:

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height = 500, bg="red")
canvas.pack()
```

Unfortunately the canvas.create_window does not work. .pack() works however is not what i need. I have looked at other examples however they are all off OOP and therefore do not find it relevant for my understanding.

Comment: Try `canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=button1)` ([reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html))

Comment: Not worked. Same result - nothing displayed

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your question lacks enough detail for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: updated with more infortmation. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CommonSense writes, try `canvas.create_window(200, 200, window=button1)`.

Also; you create `label1` inside a function and when the functioin exits the name `label1` will be garbage collected.

When you create widgets on canvas the reference is an integer; the index of that widget on the canvas. If you use the widget name as reference for the canvas widget you lose the reference to the actual widget.

Try the example below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, bg="red")
canvas.pack()

def Show_Name():
    name = 'A name' # No function NameGenerator()
    label1.config(text=name)

button1 = Button(canvas, text="Generate Name", width=20, height=4,
               command=Show_Name)
canvas_button1 = canvas.create_window(250, 300, window=button1)

label1 = Label(canvas, width=20, height=2, text="")
canvas_label1 = canvas.create_window(250, 200, window=label1)
```

Comment: Thanks. For future functions i will be creating more windows. Is it inefficient to constantly create more windows? Or should i attempt to group more widgets inside one singular window

Comment: You can create a Frame and fill it with widgets and then display the frame on the canvas with `create_window`. Works just like with a regular frame.

Comment: is that more efficient? Would you recommend that?

Comment: Well, it makes it easier to handle multiple associated widgets, if you have them. Bot if you are going to build a complex GUI then maybe you should use a regular frame instead of a canvas. The possibility is there if you like. I'd suggest you do what is simple and easy to maintain. Test both and see what you like.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!