# Python Tkinter - How to contain a widget within a Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to put an image inside the `Canvas` that has the same width as the `Canvas` but the height is according to the aspect ratio, and using a `Scrollbar` to scroll the same. Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
#Canvas and Scrollbar
img_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, height = height, width = width+15)
vsb = Scrollbar(img_canvas, orient = 'vertical')
vsb.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y')
vsb.configure(command = img_canvas.yview)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand = vsb.set)
text.window_create("end", window = img_canvas)
text.insert("end", "\n")

#Insert Image into the Canvas
im = Image.open(str(opath)+"//Ques_"+str(temp)+".png")
w, h = im.size
im = im.resize((width, int((h/w)*width)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
ques = Label(img_canvas, image = img)
ques.image = img
ques.pack(side = 'left', expand = False)
```

The problem I am encountering is that the image expands completely in `y`, and hence can't be scrolled.
I want to contain the part of the image that fits into the `Canvas`'s dimensions and the rest can be scrolled.

Comment: `canvas.create_window()` is what you looking for

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Could you please elaborate? I tried this `img_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = ques)` but now nothing seems to be displayed.

Comment: may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955586/13629335

Comment: But if you use the label just display the image this could be interesting too https://stackoverflow.com/a/43009579/13629335

Comment: @Atlas435: not necessarily. If they only want to put an image on the canvas, you can do that without using a `Label` and `create_window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `create_image` to put an image on a canvas and have it be scrollable. You can't use `pack` or `place` or `grid`. You don't need to put the image in a label first, unless you specifically want it to be a label with a border. In that case, you need to use `create_window` to add the label to the canvas.

Comment: I just have one more doubt, since all of this is going into a `Text` widget, how am I supposed to put the `Scrollbar`? As far as I am aware `Frame` doesn't get inserted into `Text` and `Scrollbar` can't have `Canvas` as the parent.

Comment: @AST: a scrollbar can have a canvas as a parent. You don't want to do that if the scrollbar is scrolling the canvas. Your question is very unclear. You are putting an image in a label in a canvas in a text widget. Why not directly add the image to the text widget, or why are you adding a canvas to the text widget? What is your ultimate goal with all of these widgets? I'm afraid you're making things way more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley, apologies for being unclear, and I really appreciate your help. Here is the link to an image <https://ibb.co/qr4349m>, this has the layout that I desire. I am using a loop to insert the same layout (on the left) into the text widget one after the other, which can can ultimately be scrolled.

Comment: @ Bryan Oakley, after trying for a while, I succeeded by inserting a `Canvas` into the `Text`, followed by packing another `Text` widget on the left and a `Scrollbar` on the right, into the canvas. Then I inserted the image into the `Text`. Would love to know if you could suggest a more efficient way of doing the same.

Comment: @AST: I would love to provide a more efficient way of doing things, but it's not really clear what you're trying to do. I don't understand why you're using a text widget at all since you don't seem to be needing to input text.

Comment: I really appreciate that, I found `Text` easier for my purpose of inserting widgets one after the other without doing much about their positioning, like I would have to do in a `Canvas`. But if you think canvas better, then I would have to work the entire part of the code again.

Comment: @AST: like I said, I don't quite understand what you're ultimately trying to do. The text widget is a great solution for scrolling a vertical stack of widgets. What I don't understand is why you think you need a text and a frame and a canvas.

Comment: Alright, please correct me if I'm wrong, since I require a scrolling image to be inserted into the text, I have thought of inserting a canvas first (because I can't insert a frame), then onto the canvas, I have 2 choices, either put another canvas or a text having the image in it, also put the scrollbar for the same. I don't think the use of a frame is necessary.

Comment: @AST: you can insert any widget into a text widget: canvas, frame, etc. Plus, there is direct support for adding images without needing another widget to hold it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll consider making some edits and try to directly utilize the text widget.